# Add an attribute to attachments

Tags: images, attachments

Currently attachments have

- title
- caption
- alt text
- description

I would like to add another attribute to that list (e.g source). How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with two filters, [`attachment_fields_to_edit`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/attachment_fields_to_edit) and [`attachment_fields_to_save`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/attachment_fields_to_save), which do exactly what their names suggest. Let's say you wan to add a `source` field. First, generate the field and fill it with its current value if that exists:

```
function wpse133608_add_attachment_location_field( $form_fields, $post ) {
    $field_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'source', true );
    $form_fields['source'] = array(
        'value' => $field_value ? $field_value : '',
        'label' => __( 'Source' ),
        'helps' => __( 'Set a source for this attachment' )
    );
    return $form_fields;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'wpse133608_add_attachment_location_field', 10, 2 );
```

Then make sure the field is saved if it has content:

```
function wpse133608add_image_attachment_fields_to_save( $post, $attachment ) {
    if ( isset( $attachment['source'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post['ID'], '_source', esc_attr($attachment['source']) );

    return $post;
}
add_filter("attachment_fields_to_save", "wpse133608_add_image_attachment_fields_to_save", null , 2);
```

Read more in [this extensive tutorial](http://www.kevinleary.net/add-custom-meta-fields-media-attachments-wordpress/).